# Python command under Windows mistaking relative for absolute path of script argument?

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

Via PowerShell, ctest and CMake's `add_test(... COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E env ...  ${Python3_EXECUTABLE} script1)`, we invoke Python script1, which contains

```
    cmd = f'python3 C:/mydir/script2.py'
    print(cmd, flush=True)
    try:
        ret = subprocess.run(cmd.split(), check=True, timeout=3)
    except Exception as err:
        print("subprocess raises", err)
        return 1
    print("command executed", flush=True)
```

The test fails with an error message that contains:

```
python3: can't open file '/c/mydir/C:/mydir/script2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Somehow `subprocess.run` mistakes the absolute path `/C:/mydir/script2.py` for a relative path, and prepends the directory `/c/mydir`. How could this happen, and how can it be prevented?

Comment: Try using forward slashes for specifying the path in the python script. Also check that it is executing the python3 executable you're expecting. It sounds like it might be using mingw or something there.